# USER DSN Entries Do Not Appear in ODBC Data Source Administrator (odbcad32.exe)

Tags: oracle, odbc

while creating DNS for my oracle 10g XE. when i click add button in user dns i did not find any option(there is only one option sqlserver)can some one please help for this.(am using windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have installed 32-bit Oracle drivers. If this is the case, you need to use the 32-bit version of the ODBC Data Source Administrator. This software is hidden under the `SysWow64` folder, eg.

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe
```

On a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, the Data Sources (ODBC) application points to the 64-bit version (`%SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe`).

Comment: Thanks Mick i found it but when i click Microsoft ODBC for oracle  i am getting this error "Oracle in XE ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 998 invalid access to memory location" please help me for this.

Comment: Add the oracle bin directory to the PATH system environment variable. e.g. C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin; in PATH as I using 11g XE